# Typeorm bulk insert entities with foreign key

Tags: javascript, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I have the following typeorm code in a for loop:

```
const user = await User.create({
    name: 'bobby',
}).save()
await Post.create({
        title: 'test'
        userId: user.id,
      }).save();
```

I tried the following code but I get an error about user.id being null:

```
const user = User.create({
        name: 'bobby',
    })
const post = Post.create({
    title: 'test'
    userId: user.id,
}).save();
await Post.insert(post);
await User.insert(user);
```

Is there a way to solve this without outright creating a entity new table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to successfully insert `User` before getting its `id`.
To minimize the number of queries, you can create and insert an array of `User` then use that users' ids to create an array of `Post` and insert it.

```
let arrayUser: User[] = [];
for(let i=0; i<num; i++){

 // create new user
 const user1 = new User();
 user1.name = 'bobby';
 arrayUser.push(user1);
}

// insert new users
const userRepo = AppDataSource.getRepository(User);
await userRepo.insert(arrayUser);


let arrayPost: Post[] = [];
for(let i=0; i<num; i++){

 // create new post
 const post1 = new Post();
 post1.title = 'test';
 post1.userId = arrayUser[i].id;
 // maybe better if you use relation: post1.user = arrayUser[i];

 arrayPost.push(post1);
}

// insert new posts
const postRepo = AppDataSource.getRepository(Post);
await postRepo.insert(arrayPost);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this also just result in 2 queries into the database, ie. a database for each .save()? So if I had 6 loops, there would be 12 resulting queries.

Comment: @jmecs Have you tried setting `user.id` manually and then use [QueryBuidlerInsert](https://typeorm.io/insert-query-builder) to insert both `User` and `Post` in one query?

Comment: @iros 
`@Field(() => Int)
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
id!: number;`

This is how I've annoted my id column. I don't think there's actually a solution if I want to automatically generate my id.

Comment: @jmecs if that is the case, I think you need at least 2 queries. one for inserting all users and one for inserting all posts.

Comment: And if these queries were in a loop that iterates 6 times there would be 12 queries, right?

Comment: @jmecs no, you can create all users and put them into an array. then insert that user array. after inserting user array, you will have user id, put those id into posts respectively and insert post array. there're totally 2 queries.

Comment: @jmecs Looks like you find it helpful, so I updated my answer.